# Angular Reactive Form Custom Remote Validation

Tags: c#, angular, api, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core Web Api and Angular. And I'm trying to implement custom validation to check if title unique or not.

I use validation service

```
 uniqueTitleValidator() : ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => { 
  if(control.value === "") {
    return  null;
  }
this.albumService.uniqueTitleValidate(control.value).subscribe((data:boolean)=>this.isExist = data);
return  this.isExist ? { titleAlreadyExists: {value: control.value}} : null;   
};
```

Here is form component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.albumForm  = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [Guid.EMPTY],
  title: ['', {
    validators: [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(15),
      Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9\' \'-'_\s]*"),
      this.titleValidator.uniqueTitleValidator()
    ],
    updateOn: 'change'
  },
  ],
  description: ['']
});
if(this.formData){
  this.albumForm.patchValue(this.formData)
}
```

And html template

```
<form [formGroup] = "albumForm" formnovalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" type="text" formControlName="title" class="form-control" required/>
    <div *ngIf="title.invalid && (title.dirty || title.touched)"
    class="error">
       <div *ngIf="title.errors?.required">
        Title is required. 
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="title.errors.maxlength">
            Title should be under 15 characters.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="title.errors?.pattern">
            Only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, ' ', '-', '_' characters are allowed.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="title.errors?.titleAlreadyExists">
           Album already exists.
        </div>
</div>      
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input id="id" type="text" class="form-control" hidden/>
    <input id="description" type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" (click)="onClick($event)" value="Save" [disabled]="!albumForm.valid" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a routerLink="/manage/albums" class="btn btn-danger ml-2">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

And controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/albums/validation")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckTitle(string title)
    {
            var album = await _albumService.GetAlbumByTitleAsync(title);
            if (album != null)
                return Ok(true);
            return Ok(false);
    }
```

But I have problem. For example: I have album in a database with a title "Album 1".
When I input invalid "Album 1" on form it shows form is valid. Then I input valid data, e.g. "Album 2", which is not in database, it shows error. It looks like form updates before value changes or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
uniqueTitleValidator() : ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => { 
  if(control.value === "") {
    return  null;
  }
this.albumService.uniqueTitleValidate(control.value)
.subscribe((data:boolean)=> {
   if (data) { 
      return {titleAlreadyExists: {value: control.value}}
   } else {
      return null
   }
});

};
```

But I guess the best practice would be that you use an [async validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-a-custom-async-validator):

Comment: Thanks a lot! Implementation of async validator solved my issue. Now it works correctly.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm very pleased to hear that!